# Why does Postgres authentication fail after deploying my Rails app to production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, deployment

It's taken me two days to get this far. But I'm almost there. When I run `cap deploy:cold` the deployment fails with this message:

```
servers: ["xxx"]
    [xxx] executing command
 ** [out :: xxx] rake aborted!
 ** [out :: xxx] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "my_app"
```

My `database.yaml` has this:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: my_app_production
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  username: my_app
  password: secret
```

I'm running `cap deploy` under a user I created called `deployer`. I installed Postgres under `deployer`. I also created the user `my_app` in psql:

```
create user my_app with password 'secret';
create database my_app_production owner my_app;
```

I verified that the user `my_app` exists by running `\du`. When I ssh through `deployer@xxx` and I run the command `psql` I get `psql: FATAL:  role "deployer" does not exist`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `psql` invocation to be similar as what rails does, it should be:

```
psql -h localhost -U my_app -d my_app_production
```

If you omit these options, `psql` will take by default:

- the OS username as the database username
- the OS username as the database name
- a Unix socket directory as the host (which differs from localhost and generally has different authentication rules in `pg_hba.conf`)

Answer (score 0):

I've gone through the very same Railscasts you are going through I think.   I just got my site up with it, though I am still having a couple glitches with cap deploy.   In any case, for clarity.

You created a deployer user on the remote host obviously.   But, that doesn't mean "deployer" is a user in Postgres.   Once you ssh as deployer@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx you have to run sudo -u postgres psql to enter psql as the default postgres admin.   Presuming you're using Ubuntu, there is no default password.

Where I'm confused is how, if you can't get in on the remote system with deployer, did you create the my_app user in psql there?   It almost sounds like you did this locally (Vagrant maybe?) and didn't do it remotely.   As I said, I think I just finished the same stuff you're looking at and it works if the my_app user is created on the remote box with the correct password.

Comment: Yes, I create `my_app` when I was sshed into `deployer`. I also set a password for `postgres` user. Those are the only two users in the db. I think Postgresql expects that the user logging into it is the same user of the system: system user = `deployer`, but Rails tries to login as `my_app`.

Comment: Can you put up your deploy script?   Again, I am doing the same railscasts you are and it does work.   Maybe you have my_app in where you need a deployer to be or something.

Comment: My deploy script is identical to Railscasts. I figured it out. The password for `my_app` was wrong. Make sure you are able to log into psql as `my_user`: `psql -h localhost -U my_app -d my_app_production` it will ask you for the password. Take a look at this gist, it has all the instructions: https://gist.github.com/abitdodgy/5600034